# dual boot windows won't detect 2k resolution after ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, resolution, dualboot

I have installed Ubuntu on my Windows 10 laptop as a second OS. I also have a second monitor, samsung g5 2k 32inch. However, after I have set my screen on Ubuntu, windows started to give me only 1080p on my second monitor. I have re-installed windows, updated, deleted, downgraded my windows drivers but I was unable to correct the issue. What might be the problem?

Comment: Does it happen after a cold boot - meaning power down and boot directly into Windows?

Comment: @harrymc yes it does happen. I have tried every driver version but not helping

Comment: You should disable Fast Startup on Windows for dual boot. Is the second monitor in Ubuntu set to 1080p?

Comment: I will search for fast startup and no, I have set it up to 2k